# Writing Integrals in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, integral

I am learning how to use LaTeX to write double and triple integrals.

The issue is about style. There is a difference between the normal integral and the double and triple one:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PREAMBULO%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PAQUETES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{comment}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COLORES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{0,128,0}
\definecolor{blanco}{RGB}{255,255,255}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%T\'{\i}TULO&%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{\textcolor{verde}{\textbf{Ayuda}}}
\author{\textcolor{verde}{\textit{Germ\'an Felipe L\'opez D\'{\i}az}}}
\date{\textit{\textcolor{verde}{23 de mayo de 2020}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%S\'{\i}MBOLOS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Z}{\mathbin}{AMSb}{"5A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\R}{\mathbin}{AMSb}{"52}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\N}{\mathbin}{AMSb}{"4E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Q}{\mathbin}{AMSb}{"51}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COMANDOS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\newcommand{\sen}{\operatorname{sen}}
\newtheorem{TEO}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{LEM}{Lema}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%DOCUMENTO%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\[\int_{X}^{Y}{\,dx} \hspace{1cm}\text{vs} \hspace{1cm} \iint_{X}^{Y}{\,dx}\]

\end{document}
```

When compiling, it writes the triple integral correctly, but it decreases the integral symbol size. Also, in contrast to the common integral, it changes the position of "X and "Y" from the right side to the bottom side. I would like to make that the symbol for multiple integrals has the same size as the common one and also that integration limits become aligned at the right side of the integral.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show us a full example document that reproduces the effect you are talking about, please? With the 'standard setup' all integral signs appear to be of roughly the same size and super- and subscripts behave the same for  `\int`, `\iint` and `\iiint`: https://gist.github.com/moewew/fd2ee6256cdf85d25f0e9aaa45b6c0fa results in https://i.stack.imgur.com/o80jX.png

Comment: Obviously yes...I just included one. Thanks for your help

Comment: `\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}` would work, but I don't know if that is the recommended solution or if what you are doing should work.

Comment: It was the key...thank you.

Comment: Make sure you’re loading all your integrals from the same package, and not loading any other version of `\int` over them.